# Laurent Expansion of a Composition (with the inverse)

Tags: complex-analysis, taylor-expansion, laurent-series, conformal-geometry, analytic-functions

Suppose $f(z) = a_1z + a_0 + O(\frac{1}{z})$ as $|z| \rightarrow \infty$. Here $a_1 > 0$. Let $W(z) = z + \frac{1}{z}$.
How do I obtain that the composite function $L(z) = W \circ f^{-1}(z)$  has the expansion $\frac{z}{a_1} - \frac{a_0}{a_1} + O(\frac{1}{z})$ as $|z| \rightarrow \infty$

Comment: $W(z) = z(1+z^{-2})$. For $f^{-1}$ you can look at $g(z) = 1/f(1/z), g^{-1}(z) = 1/f^{-1}(1/z)$, that $g$ is analytic at $z=0$ $(*)$ and $g(0)  =0,g'(0) \ne 0$ implies $g^{-1}$ is analytic at $0$ (* I assume you meant $f$ is analytic for $|z|$ large enough so that $g$ is analytic on $0<|z| < r$ and has a removable singularity at $z=0$)

Comment: Yes. $f$ is analytic for $|z|$ large enough. With $g(z) = 1/f(1/z)$ I can write $g(z)$ using $a_n$s. Then how does it translate to $g^{-1}$ and $f^{-1}$?

Comment: $h = g^{-1}, h ' = 1/g'(h)$

Comment: Thank you. Finally got it. Computation was messy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $f(z) = a_1z + a_0 + O(\frac{1}{z})$ as $|z| \rightarrow \infty$ with $a_1>0$. Consider $g(z) = \frac{1}{f(\frac{1}{z})}$. Then $g(0) = 0$ and $g'(0) \neq 0$. So $g$ is analytic near $0$ and has the form $g(z) = g_1z + g_2z^2 + O(z^3)$ near $0$. 
$$
\frac{1}{f\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)} = g(z)
$$
$$
\therefore g_1 = \frac{1}{a_1}  \text{ and } g_2 = -\frac{a_0}{a_1^2}$$
Now as the comment (above) suggests, for $g(z) = \frac{1}{f\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)}$ we have $g^{-1} = \frac{1}{f^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)}$ and $g^{-1}$ is also analytic at $0$. So $g^{-1}(z)$ is of the form $b_1z + b_2z^2 + O\left(z^3\right)$ near $0$. 
$$
(g^{-1}(g(z)))' = 1
$$
$$
\left( \frac{1}{a_1} - \frac{2a_0}{a_1^2} (b_1z + b_2z^2)) + O(z^3)\right)\left( b_1 + 2b_2z + O(z^3)\right) = 1
$$
Which gives us $b_1 = a_1$ and $b_2 = a_0a_1$
Therefore we get that $\frac{1}{f^{-1}(\frac{1}{z})} = a_1z + a_0a_1z^2 + O(z^3)$.
Now since ord$_0 f^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)) = -1$ we have $f^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)$ is of the form $\frac{c_{-1}}{z} + c_o + c_1z + O(z^2)$ near $0$. Thus
$$
\left( \frac{c_{-1}}{z} + c_0 + c_1z + O(z^2)\right)(a_1z + a_0a_1z^2 + O(z^3) = 1
$$
Which yields, $c_1 = \frac{1}{a_1}$ and $c_0 = -\frac{a_0}{a_1}$. So, $f^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{z}\right) = \frac{1}{a_1z} - \frac{a_0}{a_1} + O(z)$.

Now, $L(z) = W \circ f^{-1}(z) = f^{-1}(z) + \frac{1}{f^{-1}(z)}$. Both of these can be found by taking the reciprocals inside $f^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)$ and $\frac{1}{f^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)}$.